# Is there a “is:” filter for mail in my Gmail sent folder?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I want to create a Gmail filter that identifies all sent messages. If I were to do the same for all spam messages, I know I could use `is:spam`. Is there a similar command for sent messages? Something like `is:sentmail`?

Comment: Search right? Because you can't create an incoming filter on sent mail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sent messages are labeled as "sent", so you can use that to search for them. Either `is:sent`, `in:sent` or `label:sent` should work.

Comment: For my delegated (2nd/linked) gmail account, `is:sent` and `in:sent` seem to behave differently, showing entire conversations, not just the sent mail?

Comment: Strictly speaking `in:` returns mail in a location while `is:` searches for a status. Gmails treatment of pretty much everything as labels caps off the trilogy. For me they are essentially the same but your situation could be different.

Answer (score 3):

Some additional help.

Use gmail [shorthand](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2874/gmail_use_shorthand_when_searching_for_mail/) : l:^f – Sent Mail

See the [ultimate guide](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/gmail-advanced-search-ultimate-guide/) for more advanced searches.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), the official Gmail Help article doesn't include `is:sent` as a search operator.

I just did a couple of tests. On the Gmail web UI, is:sent is changed to in:sent while in Inbox by Gmail the search operator is unchanged but it's hard to know if the search results are the same as there isn't a total numbers of results or something similar to copare.

I think that it's better to use `in:sent` or `label:sent` because they are included in the official help articled referred above.